# Magento 1.9 - Foreach for sum values is not correct

Tags: magento-1.9, php, attributes, customer

I recollect the question because I explained myself badly in the previous one.

I have 40 clients in my Magento and I have created a custom attribute (input text) called `attribute2`. Only 3 customers have a numerical value in this attribute, the others have no value, the value of the input is empty.

In my report dashboard I wanted to create a foreach to see the sum of all the numeric values in the clients' `attribute2`. With this code it makes me the sum but there is a problem. I have seen that the foreach automatically assigns a value to the input of a customer id to those with an empty input field.

Why is this?

This is my code:

```
$CustomersId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->getCollection()->getAllIds();
$collectionCustomers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
$eavAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'attribute2');
$attributeTable = $eavAttribute->getBackendTable();


$collectionCustomers->getSelect()
        ->joinLeft(
            array('ca'=>$attributeTable),
            'ca.entity_id = main_table.customer_id',
            array('*')
        );
$collectionCustomers->addFilterToMap("attribute2","ca.value");

$sum = 0;
$result = $collectionCustomers->getData('attribute2');

foreach($CustomersId as $CustomersIds)
{
    $sum += $collectionCustomers->load($CustomersIds)->getData('attribute2');
}

echo $sum;
```

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why you apply logic like this in foreach. You can simply get total value by **count()** also.

```
$sum = [];
foreach($CustomersId as $CustomersIds)
{
    $sum[] = $collectionCustomers->load($CustomersIds)->getData('attribute2');
}

echo count($sum);
```

or if you want to get collection with specific attribute value. Then, You can get by this below code :

```
$collectionCustomers->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('attribute2', array('eq' => value_which_you_want_to_filter));
echo $count($collectionCustomers);
```

Hope, It will helpful for you.

Comment: Hi man, thanks for your answer. I'll try your code as soon as possible... ;)

Comment: So with your code the foreach will only sum inputs that have the numeric value, right?

Comment: For example if i have: <input value="23" type="text"> <input value="30" type="text"> <input value="" type="text"> function count() will display 53 how final result...

Comment: No. It will count array element. Like this => https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count.asp

Comment: You can accept answer if it will helpful for you.

Comment: I need to sum up the input values. I do not want to calculate how many arrays are. Maybe I misunderstood myself. How can I get the sum of the values of the attribute2 without counting those that have no value? Thanks